# ows_PermMask in SharePoint WebServices

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Lists.GetListItems form the Lists Web Service returns a ows_PermMask
attribute (16 character hexadecimal) for each list item.

Anyone know how this attribute maps to the user's permissions or where the
meaning of this attribute is documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site should offer you a little more detail:

http://mdasblog.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/permmask-in-sharepoint-dvwps/

It is just a built in field containing the permissions required:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.permmask.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This link also provides some good detail on PermMask:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c16aa8e4-672b-4241-a88c-6a421000e00f/setting-itemlevel-permissions-through-sharepoints-builtin-webservices?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

From the comments in that post:

"Using the PermissionMask is only for the current user... which is likely an admin user anyway which will have the permission PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff"... this is useless for most use cases of finding what users and groups have access to the item / document."

Answer (score 0):

The PermMask is very interesting stuff in SharePoint. The value of PermMask is hexadecimal. It is 16 digit (e.g 0x0000XXXXXXXX0000).

The minimum value is 0x0000000000000000 for no permission and maximum value is 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF for full permission (Basically site collection administrator).

[Bit Level Reservation of PermMask][1]

### The list and document permissions (0x000000000000XXXX) are specified as follows.

1. ViewListItems   0x0000000000000001
2. AddListItems    0x0000000000000002
3. EditListItems   0x0000000000000004
4. DeleteListItems 0x0000000000000008
5. ApproveItems    0x0000000000000010
6. OpenItems       0x0000000000000020
7. ViewVersions    0x0000000000000040
8. DeleteVersions  0x0000000000000080
9. CancelCheckout  0x0000000000000100
10. ManagePersonalViews    0x0000000000000200
11. ManageLists    0x0000000000000800
12. ViewFormPages  0x0000000000001000

### The list item permissions (0x000000000000000X) are specified as follows.

[PermMask ListItemPermissions for edit item][2]